# Android app for shared wallet/payment source

Tags: android

In the India region, is there any Android app where multiple people can share a common wallet? Or is there any app where multiple people can use same credit/debit card to make UPI/QR scan payments?

Comment: It's not possible because the mobile number linked with bank account and UPI/wallet has to be unique. Obviously more than one person cannot have the same mobile number (even for regular bank accounts two persons can't share the same number)

Comment: Also if OTP authentication of a transaction is needed, how will it work when the transaction is initiated by A but OTP goes to B? (assuming A and B have the same unique mobile number) //Think how easily frauds can happen